# how to batch insert with auto_increase id using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

batch insert data into oracle and the id is increased .how to deal ? i use the sql below all fails.

```
insert into USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES (ATTRIBUTEID, ORGANIZATIONID, 
ENTRYUUID,ATTRIBUTENAME, ATTRIBUTETYPE, ATTRIBUTESTATUS, ATTRIBUTEVALUE,
                                     USERBUCKETID)
(SELECT SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL ,'1','1','1','1','1','1',1  FROM 
DUAL) union all (SELECT SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL 
,'1','1','1','1','1','1',1 FROM DUAL)
```

another

```
INSERT ALL
INTO USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES
    (ATTRIBUTEID, ORGANIZATIONID, ENTRYUUID,ATTRIBUTENAME, ATTRIBUTETYPE, 
ATTRIBUTESTATUS, ATTRIBUTEVALUE,USERBUCKETID)
    VALUES(SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL ,'1','1','1','1','1','1',1)

INTO USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES
    (ATTRIBUTEID, ORGANIZATIONID, ENTRYUUID,ATTRIBUTENAME, ATTRIBUTETYPE, 
ATTRIBUTESTATUS, ATTRIBUTEVALUE,
     USERBUCKETID)
VALUES( SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL,'1','1','1','1','1','1',1)
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

first sql error: can not use sequence here

second sql error： Violation of unique constraints

oracle 11g

Comment: Possible duplicate of - [Inserting multiple rows with sequence in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968093/inserting-multiple-rows-with-sequence-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `UNION ALL`, use a `SELECT` statement with `CONNECT BY LEVEL` clause:

```
INSERT INTO USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES (ATTRIBUTEID, ORGANIZATIONID, 
ENTRYUUID,ATTRIBUTENAME, ATTRIBUTETYPE, ATTRIBUTESTATUS, ATTRIBUTEVALUE, USERBUCKETID)
SELECT SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL ,'1','1','1','1','1','1',1  
  FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= N; --where N is a constant value which represents the number of rows to be inserted.
```

you can even prefer using `LEVEL` pseudocolumn instead of `SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL` as a increasing integer value starting from 1.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the actual issue then @Barbaros Özhan has given the perfect answer.

But, If this is just an example and using `connect by` is not feasible in your case then you can use `deterministic function` **OR** If creating the function is not feasible in your case then you can use the following whenever you need `NEXTVAL of Sequence` in such cases.

```
to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select <YOUR_SEQUENCE_NAME>.nextval as c '
      || 'from dual'))
  returning content))
```

So your code will look like below:

```
INSERT INTO USER_MULTIVALUED_ATTRIBUTES (
    ATTRIBUTEID,
    ORGANIZATIONID,
    ENTRYUUID,
    ATTRIBUTENAME,
    ATTRIBUTETYPE,
    ATTRIBUTESTATUS,
    ATTRIBUTEVALUE,
    USERBUCKETID
)
    ( SELECT
        to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
        passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
          'select SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.nextval as c '
          || 'from dual'))
      returning content)), -- Same for the case in INSERT ALL
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        1
    FROM
        DUAL
    )
    UNION ALL
    ( SELECT
        SEQ_MAMULTIVALUEDATTRIBUTES.NEXTVAL,
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        '1',
        1
    FROM
        DUAL
    );
```

Cheers!!