# I'm getting ORA-00928 trying to insert new data

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I'm probably making a rookie mistake here, but when I try to insert new data, I get the ORA-00928 error code.  Take a look:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'GLOCK', '1982', 'PISTOLS', 'AUSTRIA')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BERETTA', '1526', 'PISTOLS', 'ITALY')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'SMITH AND WESSON', '1856', 'PISTOLS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'MOSSBERG', '1919', 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BENELLI', '1967', 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BROWNING', '1878', 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'WINCHESTER', '1866', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BUSHMASTER', '1973', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'REMINGTON', '1816', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'KLASHNIKOV', '1807', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES');
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: You're missing the `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` at the end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576/best-way-to-do-multi-row-insert-in-oracle/93724#93724

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the end of your statement:

```
SELECT * FROM dual
```

`ORA-00928` means "missing SELECT keyword". The `INSERT ALL` statement requires it, so it has the form:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO t1 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
  INTO t1 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
  INTO t1 (col1, col2, ...) VALUES (val1, val2, ...)
SELECT * FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Year_founded` column must be an INT type column, so don't use `''`
   while inserting a value into INT type column.
2. Add `SELECT * FROM DUAL`at the end.

Here is an example of the same using your query :

```
    INSERT ALL
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'GLOCK', 1982, 'PISTOLS', 'AUSTRIA')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BERETTA', 1526, 'PISTOLS', 'ITALY')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'SMITH AND WESSON', 1856, 'PISTOLS', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'MOSSBERG', 1919, 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BENELLI', 1967, 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BROWNING', 1878, 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'WINCHESTER', 1866, 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BUSHMASTER', 1973, 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'REMINGTON', 1816, 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
    INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
    VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'KLASHNIKOV', 1807, 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')

    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately, after that fix, I came across an ORA-00001 error. Evidently, by using a multi line insert with a sequence, the system tries to assign the same number to each row (due to the event occuring at the same time), violating the constraint.  Alas, it looks like I have to go with single-row inserts.

Comment: Welcome, just wanted to know that the solution that I posted was the correct solution for your ORA-00928 error that you posted right? @Lubin

Comment: There's is another way that you can do the same work in the single query,  you can simply rewrite the multi-table INSERT ALL into a single INSERT with multiple rows concatenated by UNION ALL.  Here's the reference to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60459273/11617388

Answer (score 0):

Complete script(';' should be after DUAL)

```
INSERT ALL
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'GLOCK', '1982', 'PISTOLS', 'AUSTRIA')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BERETTA', '1526', 'PISTOLS', 'ITALY')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'SMITH AND WESSON', '1856', 'PISTOLS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'MOSSBERG', '1919', 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BENELLI', '1967', 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BROWNING', '1878', 'SHOTGUNS', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'WINCHESTER', '1866', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'BUSHMASTER', '1973', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'REMINGTON', '1816', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
INTO MANUFACTURER ( MANUFACTURER_ID, NAME, YEAR_FOUNDED, SPECIALTY, ORIGIN)
VALUES (MANUFACTURER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'KLASHNIKOV', '1807', 'RIFLES', 'UNITED STATES')
select * from dual;
```